# To promote the site, follow the Music Tweeter?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

There is an (automatic, I believe) Tweeter of questions for our site:

[**Twitter account 'StackMusic'**](http://twitter.com/StackMusic)

If you follow it, your own followers and the ones you follow will have a chance to know about it through Twitter's following recommendations, and then receive tweets about recent questions asked on this site.

You can also put it in twitter lists related to music that you created.

**Update** It turns out there is also another automated twitter account:

[**Twitter account 'MusicStackEx'**](http://twitter.com/MusicStackEx)

which has a much greater group of followers, so it may be more useful...either way, they will help us get more visibility.

Comment: Looks good! I'll follow this. Perhaps we can create a Twitter 'list' for all the regular users of this site too...

Answer (score 3):

Wow... that's really bizarre. I only knew about @StackMusic, which seems to only tweet upvoted questions after a certain period, whereas @MusicStackEx seems to tweet everything, and it appears is designed to autofollow different accounts to get followers. In other words, I don't believe 90% of that account's followers have ever visited this site.

Hmm, after [some further research](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/), it appears that [@StackMusic](https://twitter.com/StackMusic) is the only "legit" Twitter, as linked [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#lifearts-traffic). It tweets "interesting content" every three hours, but will not tweet if the most "interesting content" on the site has already been tweeted.

Comment: MusicStackEx still has the old logo from Sketchy (alas, poor Sketchy)