# Vote to close this forum

Tags: discussion

I see two main reasons this "MP&P" forum is failing.

First,  the questions range from advanced queries about harmonies in specific music forms to "which note is middle C" to essentially unrelated questions about building electronics to support music production.  I realize that these can be filtered, but suspect that qualified responders tend to give up on forums w/ overly broad criteria.

Second, the number of incredibly naive questions asked by people who appear unable to understand the advice they're given is beginning to overwhelm the forum.  It's rather like the days (probably still with us) when  half of sci.physics posts were from wackos who made perpetual motion machine advocates look rational.

So we either need a way to filter or re-focus participants, or the forum will become useless.

Comment: This isn't a really a forum.

Comment: I'm not convinced but if the majority are more optimistic than I, then by all means carry on.

Comment: Though I can sense the underlying disappointment and to an extent agree with it, I might emphasize that this is not a place where *correct* people meet. This is supposed to be a hub for people (including the wackos) coming together and asking/answering questions.

Comment: 1) I don't understand why someone closes a meta question as opinion-based. 90% of meta Q are such. 2) IMHO the forum is well-defined, but simply not enough interesting (or not getting enough attention) to really survive in SE model. **I especially miss an active chat!**

Comment: It's late, but appropriate: WE'RE LEAVING BETA! :D:D:D:D:D

Comment: 2019, anyone? MSE still going strong!

Comment: Yeah,  I  was a terrible prognosticator.

Answer (score 11):

I think you are mistaken - this forum is not failing, and in fact the only factor we really need to improve is Questions per Day.

Core focus, as discussed on [this question](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/534/104), is getting more visibility.

**More visitors = more questions**

Sure, some will be rubbish, or off-topic, or too localised etc., but they are very easily dealt with: flag em! The mods will get rid of them.

Broad scopes can be fine - on gaming stack exchange I use an extensive list of ignored tags, so I don't see the plethora of questions on some game I don't care about. Here, if someone doesn't want to read about drums, they can just select drums as a tag to ignore.

So I think you are mistaken in your basic premise.

That said, I agree that energising, focusing and bringing activity are key - so what can we do about that? The linked question has some ideas, but to be honest, anything **you** can do will help.

Comment: Too localized is gone. :P hard getting used to the new ---close--- *on hold* reasons.

Answer (score 10):

It's not really a forum though, is it?  It's intended as a question/answer site and the it's to be expected that there will be a massive range of questions from the naive to the hideously complicated.

The point is you learn from the tough ones and give learning to the easy ones.  The main Site StackOverflow is riddled with the same problems, but this is the only place on the web where there's a community driven question/answer site about music and It has the potential to be a great, great resource for musicians everywhere.

An important point is that the longer that the forums go, the more likely it is that a question will have been answered before, and all you need to do there is reference the old question(and linked questions) and then the naive question will fade away.

Stick with us, this site is all about collaboration and a shared passion for our given topic.  There are no marketing forces or individual agendas at work because as soon as someone starts advertising themselves and not the topic, their reputation plummets.  This site could be paramount in pushing music theory, composition and performance into the future.

All we need is time!