# How to increase traffic?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Promoting the “Musical Practice & Performance” site](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/promoting-the-musical-practice-performance-site)

Looking at [our Area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4059/musical-practice-and-performance), we can see that we currently have around **215 visits/day**, where "1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day is worrying".

If 500 is worrying, 215 is presumably horrific. What's the best way to try to increase traffic to the site? (Presumably this is partly a chicken-and-egg problem as people are more likely to enjoy using the site if many others are online to discuss with, etc.)

Comment: Remember the stats are for where we should be at for the *end* of the public beta.  I agree we need to work on it though.

Comment: See also: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/83/promoting-the-musical-practice-performance-site

Comment: I'm also of the opinion that we should just call the stack "Music" and address more general questions as well. This will help augment traffic.

Comment: @Raskolnikov You're in favor of including questions about popular music? What (substantial, interesting) questions do you think that would add?

Comment: @MatthewRead True, but I don't know that it'll grow that much between now and then. We'll see.

Comment: @Ben: Why not? There can be interesting questions about popular music as well. As long as the question is not commercial in nature. Besides, if we have to exclude popular music, then we should exclude a larger part of jazz, a concession that nobody wants to do I think. Anyway, the point is we should broaden our scope if we want to survive. [About the title again, maybe "Musicians" is even better than "Music" as a forum title.](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/49/120)

Comment: @Ben Alpert, @Raskolnikov: Please continue these comments (about the scope of this site) in chat or post it as a separate question. Thanks.

Comment: I used twitter quite effectively for guitars.se, if one of the mods would like me to sign the account over to them i would be more than happy to.  I think it could be re-purposed for music.se since all the followers are targeted to be musicians of some type or another (the feed has dried up since the merge, but you can easily grab the music.se feed), if anyone thinks its useful.  http://twitter.com/#!/guitarstackex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget all those numbers in Area 51. **You're focusing on the wrong thing.** When users start quoting numbers and start scheming "traffic-growing" goals, I start to get nervous. The subsequent suggestions are usually counter productive to sustainable, organic growth.

Don't lose sight of the most obvious way to grow this site — provide high-quality content and draw people into your site by becoming the preeminent music Q&A destination. Google and social networking are your friend.<sup><sup>(1)</sup></sup>

We find that the best way to attract new users to the site is by **highlighting your most intriguing questions.** People *love* answering questions, and a particularly interesting and intriguing question is irresistible. It's the quickest, most definitive way to help someone realize "Yeah, this site is for me!"

**Use those social bookmarks!**

[image: Social Bookmarks]

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Seen this before? Yeah, it's a [duplicate of this response](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/promoting-the-musical-practice-performance-site). I would have thought this question should be closed as a duplicate, but many responses and comments have already been posted taking off some *off* directions, so I hope to drive this point home.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

When you see a question that doesn't have an answer or that deserves more thorough answers, try to publicize it on other sites where it may draw attention. For instance via a facebook group on music. There is a "link" button below every question and answer for that very purpose!

Answer (score 0):

The site will get evaluated in about 9 weeks. We should aim to be at 500 views in 3 weeks, 1000 views in 6 weeks and 1500 in 9 weeks. We might not hit the first deadlines due to a parabolic effect, but we should try to aim towards those numbers because it's the most optimistic increase we could have towards the amount of viewers we need to obtain.

This means, we should obtain 250 more daily viewers in 3 weeks, which is 80 / week or 10 / day. Alone, this sounds hard, but with the current set of meta users it suffices to get 1 / day more per user. Of course this might not work out great but there is *no worry* yet and we could at least try to aim towards it...

1. **Promote our website to get more activity:**

   1. [Promoting the "Musical Practice & Performance" site](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/promoting-the-musical-practice-performance-site)
   2. [To promote the site, follow the Music Tweeter?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/to-promote-the-site-follow-the-music-tweeter)
   3. [Promotion T-shirts](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148/promotion-t-shirts)
2. **Cover more topics more in-depth:**

   1. [Please help to cover more topics more in-depth.](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/please-help-to-cover-more-topics-more-in-depth)
   2. [What should our FAQ contain?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-should-our-faq-contain)
3. **Improve the quality of our site and questions**:

   1. [We should try to produce more "expert" questions](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/we-should-try-to-produce-more-expert-questions)
   2. ["The perfect conducting booklist." to "Which books could I read to become a conductor?"](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/797/revisions)